# why do not my items have any id in room database android?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I have a problem, when I insert my items in room database, they don't have an id but when I close the program and then open the program again they have one. what the problem????

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_determinig_mention);
        mentionDataBase = MentionDataBase.getInstance(DeterminigMentionActivity.this);
        intent = new Intent();
        mention = new Mention();
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && !editText2.getText().toString().equals("")) {


                    int n = Integer.parseInt(numberMax);

                    mention.number = 0;
                    mention.titleOfMention = title;
                    mention.maximomOfNumber = n;
                    mentionDataBase.mentionDao().insertMention(mention);
                    intent.putExtra("mention", mention);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(DeterminigMentionActivity.this, mention.id+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DeterminigMentionActivity.this, "کادر های خالی را پر کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
}
```

Comment: can you post your `entity` code which has your `table` and `column` definition

Comment: `@Entity(tableName = "Mention")
public class Mention implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "titleOfMention")
    public String titleOfMention;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "number")
    public int number ;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "maximomOfNumber")
    public int maximomOfNumber;

    public Mention() {}
    public Mention(String titleOfMention, int number, int maximomOfNumber) {
        this.titleOfMention = titleOfMention;
        this.number = number;
        this.maximomOfNumber = maximomOfNumber;
 }
}
`